# Resharper format multiple lines of code to a single line

Tags: format, resharper

I often use guard statements to simplify my code and return quickly when an error occurs.

Now I would like to save some space by putting these statements into a single line by selecting the text and hit a key combination.

How can I achieve this?

As example:

```
  if (!websiteValidationResult.IsSuccess)
  {
      GoToEditView(editWebsiteModel, websiteValidationResult.ErrorMessage);
  }
```

Format to:

```
if (!websiteValidationResult.IsSuccess) { GoToEditView(editWebsiteModel, websiteValidationResult.ErrorMessage); }
```

Comment: If you want to do this with even fewer characters, remove the `{` and `}` too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with ReSharper. Go to: **Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping** and select `Force put on single line` for the *Break line in a block with a single statement* rule.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This works fine but to use it as a shortcut you need to add a code cleanup profile. I added the profile, clicked on the option reformat code and now you can use (Control + E, Control + F) to format the selected code. Make sure you set "Profile to use with silent.." to your new profile.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a setting to allow a special format, for a if statement, in the Resharper settings in Visual Studio.

I'm guessing you have a lot of if statement you want to change into that perticual format?

I see two options, either try to search for custom resharper formatting or do a replace search in your code editor.